Plausibility of humans turning into mythical creatures at random
TL;DR-Lore below
If humans have a gene that turns some of them into mythical creatures, how would I justify all humans having it and the transformations only starting in the late 1900s rather than sooner?
I'm working on a story. The basic idea is that humans carry a specific gene that, on occasion, can turn them into mythical creatures. E.g., centaur, harpy, sphinx, etc. The percentage of people that this happens to is unimportant. How do I justify this happening? I am tentatively considering adding mythical creatures just as a thing that exists and was discovered when the 'mythical gene' started, but I'm not sure if that would make sense. To clarify, all people have this 'gene'. Some people who carry the gene are born mythicals, some change during childhood or puberty, and a few change as adults.
Edited for clarification:
For the purposes of asking this question, you can ignore the whole "transformation into a mythical creature". That doesn't really matter.
What I need to know is how, realistically, I can justify the entire human population carrying the same gene, that only effects about, say,
about 15% of the population.
Edit 2:
Is it plausible for the entire human race to carry a gene that only affects about 15% of the population? Real life examples welcomed.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Adult humans don't radically change shape unless bits of them come off, or they get a particularly unpleasant cancer. One gene ain't enough to describe the entire shape and function of a radically different bodyplan. And plenty of genes exist that affect some percentage of the population... blue eyes, for example, or left-handed-ness (about 10% of the population each). You're asking for what is basically a magical effect... why not just handwave it away? Not everything needs to be explained in plausible scientific detail.

I could handwave the transformation away, but I'm trying not to handwave the whole gene thing. I've edited the question, hopefully it's clearer.

If the transformation is magic, why do genetics matter?  You could say "one in eight humans is 'marked'" and it would be as meaningful.

The transformation is magic, but the magic in my world is more like "science we don't yet understand" and less "magic is magic".

It would help if you understood the difference between a locus (= physically the position of a gene and logically the function of the gene) and an allele (= any of the values which can be placed at a given locus). To continue @StarfishPrime's example, eye color is (mostly) determined by 4 loci; all humans have those for loci. But for the eyes to be blue, HERC2 must have the rs916977 single-nucleotide polymorphism, which triggers a cascade of effects.

I concur with @jdunlop. If people are turning into mythical creatures, you're much better off just having magic as the cause. Any "scientific" explanation is going to delve so far into Clarke's Law that it will just add unnecessary complexity.

Also, I love this idea as a story element. It opens up so many different interesting storylines and "what-ifs". Do people accept the demihumans as victims of fate? Do they try to kill/enslave them instead? How do the demihumans cope with the trauma of the transformation? There's so many possibilities.

It is an Epigenomic Response
Epigenomics is the study of gene activation based on environmental factors.  Just because you have a gene does not mean it will express itself.  Some genes only activate in organisms if they experience a certain amount of stress, fear, neutrant availability, hot/cold, exposure to certain chemicals etc.  These expressions can even make identical twins or clones grow up to have different entire body plans.
So, for humans to have an Epigenomic Response to something in the late 1900s, you simply need to find something about the environment that changed.  Honestly, there were a lot of changes in society in the late 1900s, but perhaps the biggest change would have been the rise in wireless communications.  Radios, cellphones, bluetooth, etc. all started bombarding our bodies with invisible EM radiation.  We just needed the genes that were able to respond to them.
That said, there is the additional concern of why people already knew about mythical creatures before the 1900s meaning that whatever stimulates the change must have existed 1000s of years ago, gone away, and then come back.  So, if you care more about mythological beasts being a modern reemergence than being something that started happening exactly in the 1990s, then lead could be a better choice.  Starting in 200BCE, the Romans used lead in a lot of products including their water pipes. The use of lead fell out of use by 250CE, and civilization stopped making wide use of lead until the 1920s when we started using it as a gasoline additive.
Alternatively, you make something that is analogous to modern Radio pollution somewhere in the ancient world.  Like an ancient Atlantis that achieved modern technology or maybe aliens came to colonize our world for a while, but then got driven off when their technology kept turning us into monsters.

Thank you for contributing! This is exactly what I've been looking for.

@Talbot Glad you like my answer, but on this stack exchange, we like to ask people to wait at least 24 hours to accept an answer since other users may have more complete, insightful, or different ideas that you might like more.  Or someone may notice a flaw in my answer that could invalidate it.

Understood. However, I would prefer to keep your answer, as it works for what I have in mind.

-1 for not writing "Epignomic". (Joke only! ;) )

POPULATION DENSITY.
The simplest answer is that until the 1900s, human population was too low for the recessive Mythic Gene to activate at any significant level.
Consider a scenario.
There is not one "Mythic Gene" but several hundred (thousands?) versions of it. You need both parents to have the same exact type of Mythic Gene to have it activate in you. So maybe 15% of humans carry some type of a Mythic Gene, but out of those, only 0,0001% are carrying the Banshee Gene, or the Sphinx Gene, or the Naglooshee gene, which are mostly not mutually compatible. So it is quite possible, that prior to say, 1800s, there were only two Banshees alive on the planet at the same time, and they were siblings already. Since there were no Banshee Gene carriers for them to mate with, and it was not possible to even know who is a carrier before the invention of science of genetics, they both just mated with Normals and their Mythic Gene became dormant in the offspring again.
Example: Your Dad had the Sphinx Gene, your Mother was "Normal". You are born Normal, but potentially carry the Sphinx Gene.
Example 2: your Dad had the Sphinx Gene, your Mother had the Harpy Gene. You are born Normal, possibly carry both Mythic Genes, or either. Extremely rarely, you can have them combine into a Manticore Gene.
Example 3: Both your Mom and Dad have the Sphinx gene, you are born with the potential to develop into a Sphinx.
Prior to the globalization of the 1900s, the chances of your Sphinx Gene Mom and Sphinx Gene Dad ever meeting were abysmally low. It happened on occasion, hence the ancient myths about Harpies and Giants, and Sphinxes and Trolls (the myth of the Minotaur being the perfect example), but 99.9999% of those Mythic Creatures died childless or had only human children with human partners, because they could not find a mythic mate that was not already their parent or sibling. Not to mention, most Mythicals cannot mate with humans due to anatomical differences, and thus cannot even interbreed with human Mythic Gene Carriers. Sometimes, clusters of Mythic Creatures would try inbreeding to preserve their bloodline, but this inevitably led to mutation, genetic diseases and extinction.
Moreover, being Mythic is rarely rarely beneficial to survival outside some specific circumstances. Yes, there are evolutionary pressures when, say, "turn into a griffin" is an optimal evolutionary strategy, but 99% of cases, Mythical creatures are large, predatory, energy-inefficient, and would starve to death sooner than an ordinary human. Of all kinds of Mythical Monsters, the Long Ape (homo sapiens sapiens) hominid form is by fare the most energy efficient and suited to the most kinds of environments.
Therefore, the sudden explosion of the number of Mythicals could only have happened when there was enough calorie surplus created by the civilization for the Mythicals to survive, AND enough population + international travel for Mythicals to meet potential mates.
A simple example: It would be very possible for a man in Ireland to carry the Banshee gene, but if the closest woman with the Banshee Gene is a Cherokee, no actual Banshee child can be produced until way after the colonization of Northern America.
